# Angular Material autocomplete validate only the options on the list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Application, I want to implement and Autocomplete Dropdown in my Application,
I checked the sample code from Angular material, its not perfect, and does allow users to type even after they select an option. and it does not validate.
I want something like this (https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0Bn1j )
and my options should be as Key Value, Key should be CountryID and Value should be CountryName
I am new to This any help would be appreciated.
I saw an example here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-validation-example.html)
but its options is string
my option is coming from database table with CountryId and CountryName

component.ts:

```js
     function autocompleteStringValidator(validOptions: Array<string>):   ValidatorFn {
    console.log(validOptions);
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (validOptions.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
      return null  /* valid option selected */
    }
    return { 'invalidAutocompleteString': { value: control.value } }
    }
    }

    
     
    export class TasksformComponent implements OnInit {

     
     public phoneLabelOptions: any[] = [];
     public filteredPhoneLabelOptions: Observable<any[]>
     public phoneLabelAutocompleteControl = new FormControl('', 
      { validators: [autocompleteStringValidator(this.phoneLabelOptions), Validators.required] })

      public validation_msgs = {
        'contactAutocompleteControl': [
          { type: 'invalidAutocompleteObject', message: 'Contact name not recognized. Click one of the autocomplete options.' },
          { type: 'required', message: 'Contact is required.' }
        ],
        'phoneLabelAutocompleteControl': [
          { type: 'invalidAutocompleteString', message: 'Phone label not recognized. Click one of the autocomplete options.' },
          { type: 'required', message: 'Phone label is required.' }
        ]
      }

        private _filterPhoneLabels(label: any): any[] {
      console.log('---cling----');
      console.log(label);
      if (label === '') {
        return this.phoneLabelOptions.slice()
      }
      const filterValue = label.toLowerCase()
      return this.phoneLabelOptions.filter(option => option.Name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))
     }

      ngOnInit(): void{
       
         this.filteredPhoneLabelOptions = this.phoneLabelAutocompleteControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => {
        console.log('---ite here----');
        console.log(value);
        return this._filterPhoneLabels(value)
      })
     )
       
      let lookupTablename: string;
      console.log('------'+this.categoryID);
      this.selected = this.categoryID;
      this.lookupService.getLookupByTableAlias((lookupTablename = 'category')).subscribe(
      (icategory: any) => {
        this.category = icategory;
        //console.log(icategory);
        icategory.forEach((item)=>{
          this.phoneLabelOptions.push({ID:item.ID, Name:item.Name});
        });
        console.log(this.phoneLabelOptions);
      },
      error => {
        const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog('Server Error', 'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.', 'Close', 'Try Again');
        res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
          if (dialogResult) {
            this.callNext(4000);
          }
        });
        }
      );
     }
```

component.html:

```html
            <mat-form-field>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone label" aria-label="Phone label" matInput 
                        [formControl]="phoneLabelAutocompleteControl" [matAutocomplete]="autoPhoneLabel">
                        <mat-autocomplete #autoPhoneLabel="matAutocomplete">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let label of filteredPhoneLabelOptions | async" [value]="label.ID">
                            {{label.Name}}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                
                        <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of validation_msgs.phoneLabelAutocompleteControl">
                          <div *ngIf="phoneLabelAutocompleteControl.hasError(validation.type)">
                            {{validation.message}}
                          </div>
                        </mat-error>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can work with mat-auto-complete.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-validation-example.html)

All you have to do is to provide the values in the array as well.

```
  public contactOptions: Contact[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Elton John', value:'elton'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Elvis Presley', value:'Elvis'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Paul McCartney', value:'Paul'}
  ]
```

And the value can be set to either string or number from the interface.

```
export interface Contact {
  name: string;
  value:string;
  id: number;
}
```

Alright, now we are halfway done. Once the dropdown value is selected, you will be able to get the name. With that name, you can just add find() method in your `contactOptions` array and fetch the respected value and you are done.

```
let result:any = this.contactOptions.find(res=> res.name === selectedValue); 
let value = result.value; //===> value: '' from object
let id = result.id
```

Comment: i took ss of the link the op provided.

Comment: You could also explain the code inline if you're using a textual version.

Comment: If you can see in my code I need the value to be ID which is number not string

Comment: which value do you want to be ID ? Are you talking about the interface?

Comment: Yes, and those filter functions checks by string first once I select as I select the value which is ID it give error of converting to lowercase and the number displays in the dropdown

Comment: My bro you can add anything in interface. Thats one of the basics to know. I am updating my answer. Althought this basic thing is something you should be doing yourself but since you asked i will do it.

Comment: You can check now.

Comment: I put my whole functions check it and let me know

Comment: What do you want me to check!

Comment: when I type in dropdown it displays the options when I select the options it sets the value to the ID value, that is correct because I want to send the Id of the dropdown back and it should display the Name after I select which it doesn't right now

Comment: Bro, you can fetch the ID on button submission  with the filter method I used in my answer simple as that. It will not set it backwards but you can fetch the id with the selected value.